# Django site using prototype.js not working on IE8

Tags: ajax, django, forms, internet-explorer-8, prototypejs

Referring to the other question I asked [Django using AJAX with Forms, Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608932/django-using-ajax-with-forms-views), I got the django site to work with FF and Chrome but its not working with IE8. It doesn't show any error. Just the data I had in the 2nd drop down disappears and the drop down is not updated with data. No error nothing. Is there a way to see if anyone else had this issue?

Comment: Have you tried [ie8 dev tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628.aspx)? They have a JS debugger so you can try it to understand what's really going on inside.

Comment: I did. Nothing is showing. The only thing that happens on IE when the event is fired is that the prepopulated ---------- in the dropdown disappears. Is there anything that I need to do in the JS debugger so I can see what is going on? I m not that familiar with IE dev tools.

Comment: Actually I haven't used it too :) But it should have some kind of breakpoints and `console.log` stuff so you can watch your variables in JS and try to understand what is ie doing inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to use JQuery lib instead of prototype and everything is working fine.